# How do I mimic `ls foo*bar` in R?

Tags: r, string-matching

Completely stumped, though it seems like a simple question that will be voted down very shortly as a duplicate, but I couldn't find the right "pattern" to search for the answer.

I am looking for files in a folder that match a dual pattern and then want to open them in R. So, assume `list.files` produces the following:

```
lf <- c("foo_23_bar.txt", "goo_42_mar.txt", "boo_42_bar.txt")
```

In command line, I would use `ls foo*bar` to find the first file, but in R, something like,

```
grep(paste("foo","bar",sep="|"),lf)
```

returns both files 1 and 3. I am not sure how to use the `perl=TRUE` option. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If `bar` always follows `foo` you can do: `grep("foo.*bar", lf)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use the system function. Check out here. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.html

Answer (score 4):

Use `glob2rx` to get the corresponding regex

```
> glob2rx("foo*bar*")
[1] "^foo.*bar"
```

and

```
> grep(glob2rx("foo*bar*"), lf, value=TRUE)
[1] "foo_23_bar.txt"
```

Comment: Hmm .. when I try `grep(glob2rx("foo*bar"),lf,perl=TRUE)`, or some variant, I get `integer(0)`. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm .. one of the useful answers has disappeared. Anyway, here is exactly what I had in mind, combining Martin's and Michael's(?) answers:

```
list.files(path="data/",pattern=glob2rx("*foo*bar*"))
```

Or, as solved by Bingjun:

```
lf <- system("ls data/*foo*bar*")
```

This has the added benefit of providing filenames with path, making it simpler to read them into R directly.